# Parallel Computation with nngraph Torch

Tags: neural-network, torch

I thought that nngraph was supposed to make writing neural networks with complex structures (for example, parallel computations) a lot easier, but I ran into some bugs..

Is the main advantage of nngraph the ability to plot the graph afterwards, and also the possibility to chain the modules quite easily?

Why do I have a bug with this:

```
lookup = nn.LookUpTable(...)
question = lookup(input[1])
answer = lookup(input[2])
```

or maybe I should do something like

```
question, answer = lookup({input[1],input[2]}
```

?

(input[1] and input[2] are just tensors containing integers)
(The bug is that one of question or answer doesn't have a correct output. Dimensions are off, etc.)

**Do I have to use ParallelTable even when using nngraph, in a case like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, apparently this is independent from nngraph.

What you should do in this case is clone your module, and use the clone:

```
lookup2 = lookup:clone()
```

lookup and lookup2 will share the same parameters.